# How to combine Codrops tutorial codes into a SilverStripe project?

Tags: javascript, npm, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I love all the tutorials and code examples on the Codrops website. [Codrops Website](https://tympanus.net/codrops/)
I would like to include some of them in my SilverStripe projects. [SilverStripe CMS](http://silverstripe.org)

I've learnt how to install them to my site theme folder using NPM.
The question is where is the best place to install all the dependencies like the **node_modules** folder. I'm breaking up the HTML code from the **index.html** file inside the **src** folder that comes with the NPM install from the tutorial and adding them to the CSS and JS folders for a SilverStripe project.

I am specifically trying to install this module:
[Letters Animation by Codrops](https://github.com/codrops/LettersAnimationLayout)

I'm trying to work this out for myself whilst still asking if anyone has direct advice for best practice for adding these modules to SilverStripe.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you don't have any prior experience developing with Silverstripe CMS. I recommend you check out the [getting started docs](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/getting_started/) and [the lessons](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/lessons/) which should walk you through all you need to know.

You aren't likely to get any specific advise for using Codrops tutorials in Silverstripe CMS, but it sounds like you have a bunch of static HTML code which you want to convert to use dynamic data from Silverstripe? If that's the case, lesson 2 covers that use case.

> The question is where is the best place to install all the dependencies like the node_modules folder

You don't want to expose the actual dependencies. You'll want to build out some distribution files and then expose *those*. It's pretty standard to put them in `app/client/dist`, with the source files in `app/client/src` - or you can put them somewhere appropriate in your theme (e.g. `themes/my-theme/client/`). You can then [expose the dist files](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/templates/requirements/#exposing-assets-webroot) by adding this to your composer.json file:

```json
"extra": {
    "expose": [
        "app/client/dist"
    ]
}
```

and then running `composer vendor-expose`.

You can [include those dist files in your templates](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/developer_guides/templates/requirements/#template-requirements-api) using `<% require javascript("app/client/dist/some_file.js") %>` or `<% require themedJavascript("client/dist/some_file") %>`

You can also include those dist files [in your response via PHP](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/developer_guides/templates/requirements/#php-requirements-api) from your page controller:

```php
Requirements::javascript('app/client/dist/some_file.js');
// or 
Requirements::themedJavascript('client/dist/some_file');
```

Disclaimer: The code I've written above is from memory. If it doesn't work immediately, refer back to the documentation I've linked to.

Comment: I appreciate your response! I do have experience developing SS sites and creating dynamic content etc. But totally unfamiliar with json files and how to use them. Converting the static HTML file from the tutorial is fine and including the JS / CSS files. But as you've highlighted above there are better methods. If someone wanted to write up a full example of applying a Codrops tutorial into a SS site. I could give a big bounty! There's so many of them I want to use. I'm looking into all the comments you made. Thank you